# npm run dev script error

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

I'm trying to follow a tutorial and i continue running into an error with has to do with the script.

I've restarted the tutorial to try to make sure I didn't miss anything however I've hit the same road block. I'm on a mac in pycharm.

So far in the tutorial (its off of udemy)we have installed the webpack-cli, webpack, and created a test.js file to see if importing and exporting modules work.

test.js

```
console.log('imported module');

export default
```

Index.js

```
// Global app controller

import num from './test';

console.log(`I imported ${num} from another module`);
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "forkify",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "forkify project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.11.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "Christopher Maltez",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/js/index.js',
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname,'dist/js'),
      filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    mode: 'development'
};
```

and here is the error log.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'dev' ]
2 info using npm@6.1.0
3 info using node@v8.11.2
4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
5 info lifecycle forkify@1.0.0~predev: forkify@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle forkify@1.0.0~dev: forkify@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle forkify@1.0.0~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle forkify@1.0.0~dev: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/chrismaltez/Desktop/pycharmprojects/UDEMY/JS-Udemy/Section 9: forkify/9-forkify-starter/node_modules/.bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Users/chrismaltez/anaconda3/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Users/chrismaltez/anaconda3/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin/:/usr/local/mysql/bin/
9 verbose lifecycle forkify@1.0.0~dev: CWD: /Users/chrismaltez/Desktop/pycharmprojects/UDEMY/JS-Udemy/Section 9: forkify/9-forkify-starter
10 silly lifecycle forkify@1.0.0~dev: Args: [ '-c', 'webpack' ]
11 info lifecycle forkify@1.0.0~dev: Failed to exec dev script
12 verbose stack Error: forkify@1.0.0 dev: `webpack`
12 verbose stack spawn ENOENT
12 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:48:18)
12 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
12 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
12 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
12 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
13 verbose pkgid forkify@1.0.0
14 verbose cwd /Users/chrismaltez/Desktop/pycharmprojects/UDEMY/JS-Udemy/Section 9: forkify/9-forkify-starter
15 verbose Darwin 17.5.0
16 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
17 verbose node v8.11.2
18 verbose npm  v6.1.0
19 error file sh
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno ENOENT
22 error syscall spawn
23 error forkify@1.0.0 dev: `webpack`
23 error spawn ENOENT
24 error Failed at the forkify@1.0.0 dev script.
24 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
25 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Here is a snippet of my file structure where I think is the problem. 
[image: file structure]

Comment: is 'webpack' installed globally or locally. Node is not finding 'webpack'

Comment: By his package.json @RobertRowntree it is locally. He might have global and local, try removing all instances of webpack that you have.

Comment: I just removed local and global versions and tried `npm install webpack --save-dev` . now when i try to run npm run dev, i get `sh: webpack: command not found` along with `npm ERR! Failed at the forkify@1.0.0 dev script.
`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

a friend and I figured it out. Weirdly enough, I had to use the command: `npm link webpack` to link it in from the global dependencies. Once that worked, i unlinked and then ran `npm install webpack --save-dev` and after that it started working. i dont know why it wasnt finding it from the local dependencies from when i had originally installed it.

Thank you all for your help.

***update***

the same thing just happened with: `npm install webpack-dev-server --save-dev`

i think it might have something to do with me potentially not being admin. everytime i have to install I have to enter `sudo` i thought i only had to do that if i wasnt the admin. Feel free to enlighten me about that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm also following the same tutorial and had the same issue.

I tried all the above solutions and nothing worked.

I also tried what Jonas said on "Note lecture 133" to use the new updated command line, which also didn't work before his "lecture 134" about webpacks:

`npm install --save-dev webpack@4 webpack-cli@2 webpack-dev-server@3`

So, heres how I got `npm run dev`working:

If you watched carefully on "Lecture 134 and 135" Jonas was using `webpack 4.2.0`, `webpack-cli 2.0.12` and there wasn't any `webpack-dev-server` installed either.

If you installed webpack previously, do the following:

On terminal, cd to the directory of the "9-forrkify" folder where you installed webpack and run the follow commands to uninstall webpack:

`npm uninstall webpack-dev-server --save`

`npm uninstall webpack-cli --save`

`npm uninstall webpack --save`

To install webpack correctly to follow along the tutorial, run the command:

`npm install --save-dev webpack@4.2.0 webpack-cli@2.0.12 webpack-dev-server@3.1.1`

`npm run dev` should work now properly with no errors at the console on chrome web browser.

For anyone that curious what tutorial we are all talking about:

"The Complete JavaScript Course 2020: Build Real Projects!"
Here is the link: https://www.udemy.com/course/the-complete-javascript-course/

Comment: In my case, it was just a typo in webpack config file. Now running fine without downgrading the package versions.

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT*: For some reason my answer was downvoted, but it actually works. Give it a try.**

I believe the problem is that you're trying to use `webpack` but it's not installed globally. You should be able to fix this by using `npx` (a tool that comes installed with `npm`) to execute a locally installed package.

In your `package.json`, try changing:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack"
 }
```

To this:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npx webpack"
}
```

Let me know if this solves your problem!

Comment: he has webpack in his dependencies, by running that it'll call the local webpack. No need to run global with npx.

Comment: @MatheusSilva npx runs local packages, not global ones. Your misunderstood my answer, it works perfectly.

Comment: okay so i tried the npx way but that didnt do it unfortunately. it then asks me to install either webpack-cli or webpack-command but i already have webpack-cli installed. regardless, i choose webpack-cli in and then i get an error saying 

`{ Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-cli'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)`

Comment: First, make sure `webpack` is installed: `npm install --save-dev webpack`. If you're using webpack v4 or later, you'll need to install a CLI, too: `npm install --save-dev webpack-cli` And in your `package.json`, change your start script to this: `"start": "webpack --config webpack.config.js"` where *webpack.config.js* is your project's webpack configuration file. Let me know if this solves your problem.